# How to install CoffeeCup Visual Site Designer Software on Ubuntu 12.04 or +?

Tags: 12.04

Hello. My question is somewhat important toward the Ubuntu. My question is, " How do you install CoffeeCups "Visual Site Designer program". I went throught PlayOnLinux method, but it has a complication error in the beginning and after all the installion, it still does not work. Is there a certain method of installion method for this certain program. If's possible can you please describe the method please.

Answer (score 2):

You should first install wine by typing `sudo apt-get install wine` in a terminal. Then simply click on the installation file (.exe probably) and you should be able to install and run it under Wine Windows Program Loader.